# Docker can't foward a port to access a postgres database service running on host machine

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using Arch Linux, and Postgresql v.16.

Postgres is installed on my machine, DBeaver and my app CAN access normally my Postgres Database.

However, when I try to run my application via Docker, the following message appears:

`docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint wizardly_clarke (9993a1ecda871726d4a21a13fedc31b898d6264e4654324bd452fdb4de04b0ac): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled`

This is the command I run:

`docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -p 5432:5432 joaofilippe/todo_go:0.1`

I tried to allow Docker on pg_hba.conf and run Postgres with DockerCompose. In this last case, I used the port 5430 and gets the same result: port 5430 already in use.

UPDATE
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go. Sum ./
RUN go mod download

ENV ENV=PROD

EXPOSE 5432

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o ./cmd/server ./cmd/main. Go

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /app/cmd/server /app/cmd/server
COPY --from=builder /app/config /app/config

WORKDIR /app/cmd
ENTRYPOINT [ "./server" ]
```

These DockerFile, yamls file and commands works with no problem on Windows.

UPDATE

The command which worke was:

`docker run -it -p 3000:3000 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway joaofilippe/todo_go:0.1`

Comment: Are you trying to run Postgres in a container or just want your app running in the container to access Postgres DB running on your host machine?

Comment: I want my app, which is running in container, to access PostegresDB. But wen I foward the port, I get this message from docker